# Consultas SQL, Suma, especificacion de suma

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

tengo un problema en este ejercicio de consulta de sql, que dice:

**"Listado de la suma de las ventas (TotalDue) realizadas agrupadas por TerritoryID  en los que la suma se encuentre entre  5.000.000  y 8.000.000 "**

el problema es que no encuentro como especificarle que solo me muestre el resultado de las sumas que sean superiores a 5.000.000 y inferiores a 8.000.000....

`select SUM(TotalDue) as [Suma TD], TerritoryID from Sales.SalesOrderHeader group by TerritoryID`

trate de poner un `WHERE SUM(TOTALDUE) > 5000000 AND SUM(TOTALDUE) < 8.000.000`

Comment: Usa la clausula HAVING en vez de WHERE

Comment: select SUM(TotalDue) as [Suma TD], TerritoryID
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
Having SUM(TOTALDUE) > 5000000 AND SUM(TOTALDUE) < 8000000
group by TerritoryID

me dice sintaxis incorrecta de group

Comment: Es porque está mal colocada. Se coloca después del GROUP BY. Revisa la sintaxis en linea

Comment: ok ya funciona gracias

Comment: Ahora responde a tu pregunta con detalles de lo que hiciste y como funciona para que completes tu proceso de aprendizaje.

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUM(TotalDue) as [Suma TD], TerritoryID
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
group by TerritoryID
Having SUM(TOTALDUE) > 5000000 AND SUM(TOTALDUE) < 8000000
```

el objetivo es sumar las TotalDue de la tabla **Sale.SalesOrderHeader** y agruparlos por el **TerritoryID**... Despues especificar que sumas quieres ver (en este caso el ejercicio pedia ver las sumas que estaban entre el rango 5000000 y 8000000